# How do I extend a regular expression to exclude all files in a folder?

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

In the app.yaml file of my Google App Engine project there is a skip_files section used to exclude files of given types from being uploaded. How do I extend this regular expression to exclude the entire gaeunit directory from being uploaded?

```
skip_files: |
    ^(.*/)?(
    (app\.yaml)|
    (index\.yaml)|
    (\..*)|
    (.*\.pyc)|
    (.*\.bat)|
    (.*\.psd)|
    (Thumbs.db)|
    (.*\.svn/.*)|
    (.*\.lnk)|
    (.*\.datastore)|
    (_darcs/.*)|
    (nbproject/.*)|
    (.*\.swp)|
    (.*\.log)|
    )$
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The same way the `nbproject` and `darcs` directories are excluded in the above regular expression. Add this line anywhere before the last line:

```
(gaeunit/.*)|
```

Answer (score 6):

my app.yaml looks like this:

```
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?#.*#
- ^(.*/)?.*~
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*
- ^(.*/)?\..*
- ^(statistics/.*)
- ^(unittests/.*)
- ^(webtests/.*)
```

Comment: Not sure if they're needed.

Comment: well not for the last 3, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

With a new app (as of this writing) you can simply put the directory name with a trailing slash (as indicated by the [app.yaml docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#skip_files))

So your app.yaml might look like:

`skip_files:
- node_modules/
- ^(.*/)?app\.yaml
- ^(.*/)?app\.yml
- ^(.*/)?index\.yaml
- ^(.*/)?index\.yml
...`

However, when trying to ignore a huge directory like node_modules, you will find the following easier to deal with: (`- ^node_modules/*.*`). This solution will print a single, nice message like `INFO: Ignoring directory [node_modules]: Directory matches ignore regex.` when deploying with `gcloud app deploy`.

Unfortunately `gcloud app deploy` will still locally copy all files in the deploy directory to `/var/folders/...` even though you have ignored certain directories/files. Those files won't be uploaded to google though.