# app.yaml skip_files skip an entire directory but one individual file

Tags: regex, google-app-engine, yaml

I have an `app.yaml` file in which I want to skip the entire `node_modules` directory save for one file I added called `helpers.js`. Currently my file looks like this:

```
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
skip_files:
 - ^node_modules$
```

What's the best way of skipping the entire `node_modules` directory **except** for `helpers.js`?

Comment: it's not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: @sweaver2112 I am asking for a regex which will exclude all files in the `node_modules` directory except for `helpers.js`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would appear you can [just use a negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34138668/244811) in your regex to do this:

```
^node_modules/(?!node\.js$).*
```

*[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889151/how-do-i-extend-a-regular-expression-to-exclude-all-files-in-a-folder) may be useful to you also.

Comment: for new runtimes it seems this is no longer supported and you need to use .gcloudignore files, which basically follows the same syntax as .gitignore